# Convert Terraform Templates to Cloudformation Templates

Tags: aws-cloudformation, terraform

I want to convert the existing terraform templates(hcl) to aws cloudformation templates(json/yaml).

I basically want to find security issues with these templates through CFN_NAG.

An approach that I have already tried was converting HCL to JSON and then passing the template to CFN_NAG but I received a failure since both the templates have different structure.

Can anyone please provide any suggestions here?

Comment: You should provide an example here to help illustrate the issue you encountered.

Answer (score 17):

**[2024 Update. AWS's CloudFormer has now been retired. There is a 3rd part product [Former2](https://former2.com) that does the same thing. But the author has not yet tried it.]**

A rather convoluted way of achieving this is to use Terraform to stand-up actual AWS environments, and then to use AWS’s [CloudFormer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) to extract  CloudFormation templates (JSON or YAML) from what Terraform has built. At which point you can use [cfn-nag](https://stelligent.com/2016/04/07/finding-security-problems-early-in-the-development-process-of-a-cloudformation-template-with-cfn-nag/).

CloudFormer has some limitations, in that not all AWS resources are currently supported (RDS Security Groups for example) , but it will get you all the basic AWS resources.

Don't forget to remove all the environments, including CloudFormer's, to minimise the cost.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use static code analysis to find security issues in your Terraform setup.

Trying to converting Terraform to CloudFormation to later use cfn-nag is one way. However, there exist tools now that directly operate on the Terraform setup.

I would recommend to take a look at [terrascan](https://github.com/cesar-rodriguez/terrascan). It is built on [terraform_validate](https://github.com/elmundio87/terraform_validate).

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/bridgecrewio/checkov/ runs security scanning for both terraform and cloudformation